# How to get locale of string on android?

Tags: java, android

I want to know what is the **locale** of input text in edittext!
However i tried to get the keyboard locale but that wasn't helpful.
I don't want to type english in the edittext so help me!
I want user to know that he/she can't type english!

Sorry for my bad english!

Here is my code :

```
  edtUsernameLogin.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
            if (editable.toString().isEmpty()) {
                mtfUsernameLogin.setLabelColor(G.resources.getColor(R.color.cpb_white), "نام کاربری");
            } else {
                String locale = G.inputMethodManager.getCurrentInputMethodSubtype().getLocale();
                if (locale.equals("fa") || locale.equals("ar")) {
                    mtfUsernameLogin.setLabelColor(G.resources.getColor(R.color.sPink), "نام کاربری باید انگلیسی باشد !");
                } else {
                    mtfUsernameLogin.setLabelColor(G.resources.getColor(R.color.sGreen), "نام کاربری");
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: if I understand correctly, u want to open keyboard as per the phone's language ?

Comment: IMHO only way either get default device language or detect language from text entered in the edittext

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?  Its hard to stop a user from typing in english if he decides to.  You could set a filter that disallows latin characters, but that only works if your language doesn't use them either, and would be actively annoying to a bilingual user or a user that has to use an english word for technical or jargon purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Solution is :

```
InputFilter usernameFilter = new InputFilter() {
        @Override
        public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
            String blockCharacterSet = " اآبپتثجچحخدذرزژسشصضطظعغفقکگلمنوهی";
            if (blockCharacterSet.contains(source)) {
                edtNameEdit.setHintTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.grey));
                edtNameEdit.setHint("نام و نام خانوادگی");
                return source.toString();
            } else {
                edtNameEdit.setHintTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.sPink));
                edtNameEdit.setHint("نام و نام خانوادگی باید فارسی باشد!");
                return "";
            }
        }
    };
    edtNameEdit.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{usernameFilter});
```

**And important line :**

```
    edtNameEdit.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_NO_SUGGESTIONS);
```